# Chapter style ger in memoir class

Tags: memoir

I'm having a problem with the `ger` chapter style included in the `memoir` class. Fig. 6.17 of the `memoir` manual shows an example of the `ger` style.

The `ger` style displays the chapter number, e.g., Chapter 1, on the first line, and the chapter title on a line below the number as in

Chapter 1
Chapter Title

The manual's illustration shows that the typeface size of the chapter number is smaller than that of the chapter name.

My problem is that both chapter number and title have the same typeface size.

Here's an excerpt of my source code. It's not an MWE because the source is quite complicated, for example, I use Open Type fonts and XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\frontmatter

\chapterstyle{ger}

\mainmatter

%---------------Chapter 1---------------------

\chapter{Introduction} \label{ch:Ch1intro}

\end{document}
```

The output reads

Chapter 1

Introduction

I will appreciate suggestions for making the typeface of the chapter number smaller than that of the chapter title.

Comment: I've formatted code here (you can do this by selecting the code and clicking on the `{}` icon. For inline code use backticks. (``). I've also removed your name and thanks from the question which are unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class is *extremely* well documented, so it really is worth it to read through it, as almost all your `memoir` questions are likely to be covered in it.

The chapter number and chapter name formatting are controlled by the macros following macros, described on p. 86 of the documentation.

```
\chapnamefont
\chapnumfont
```

So it is sufficient to change these to whatever meets your needs. With the `ger` chapter style, they are set as `\Huge`. We can make them smaller like this. Note also that I've moved the `\chapterstyle` command and the commands to change the format to the preamble, rather than after `\begin{document}` where they are in your sample code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{ger}
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\Large}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}



\frontmatter


\mainmatter

%---------------Chapter 1---------------------

\chapter{Introduction} \label{ch:Ch1intro}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]